# Converting A String Into a Nested JSON Object

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if this was possible without eval (i hear it's evil).

```
var myString = 'myObject.property.subproperty';
```

and convert it to

```
var obj = {
    myObject: {
        property: {
            subproperty: {}
        }
    }
};
```

Been at this for 2 hours.

The val solution that I don't like:

I can do it with input string.

```
var myString = 'myObject.property.subproperty';
var nameTree = myString.split('.');
var evalString = '';
var myObj = {};
_.forEach(nameTree, function(value, key){

    if (key == 0) {
        evalString += 'myObj[' + value + '] = {};';
    } else {
        evalString += '[' + value + '] = {};';
    }
});

eval(evalString);
```

I get:

```
console.log(myObj);

// {myObject: {property:{subproperty:{}}}};
```

Comment: basically, given that input, you'll have to do it yourself.  you can just use a self made function using split in a recursive fashion

Comment: I'm not sure what `eval()` has to do with your question because you can't even use it to make what you want from your input string.  Anyway, here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Q9cWa/ using the same technique hugomg showed (who happens to type faster than I so posted an answer sooner).  My version is put into a function.

Comment: @jfriend00 edited question to show the eval solution I mentioned. But it's evil. I burned it before it laid eggs.

Comment: OK, yep that's evil.  That's even more complicated than not using `eval()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you can use to solve your problem is dynamic property access using string indexing. `obj["foo"]` is the same as `obj.foo`.

```
var properties = myString.split('.');
var obj = {};
var curr = obj;
for(var i=0; i<properties.length; i++){
    var next = {}
    curr[properties[i]] = next;
    curr = next;
}
```

Comment: This would give me a flat object. Or you pressed enter too fast?